# Perl on Modules-Inheritance,Polymorphism

Tags: perl

This is a question from object oriented Perl. I am supposed to design a module:
1)Store the values
2)Calculate the Total, Mean, Count.
I am supposed to find a code which relates method overriding or polymorphism or inheritance in Object Oriented Perl.

My code is like this:

```
package Stats;
use strict;
use warnings;
sub new {
  my $class = @_;
  my $self = {};
  bless $self, $class;
  $self->clear();
  return $self;
}
sub clear {
  my $self = $_[0];
  $self->{'numlist'} = undef;
  $self->{'x_sum'} = 0;
  $self->{'x2_sum'} = 0;
}
sub addValue {
  my $self = $_[0];
  my $num = $_[1];
  if (defined $num) {
    push @{$self->{'numlist'}}, $num;
    $self->{'x_sum'} += $num;
    $self->{'x2_sum'} += $num**2;
  }
}
sub getTotal {
  my $self = $_[0];
  return $self->{'x_sum'};
}
sub getMean {
  my $self = $_[0];
  my @numlist = @{$self->{'numlist'}};
  if (!@numlist) { return 0; }
  return $self->getTotal()/@numlist;
}
sub getValueList {
  my $self = $_[0];
  return @{$self->{'numlist'}};
}
1;


sub results {
my $obj = new Stats(13,4,56,43,33);
print "Number of values: ", scalar($obj->getValueList()), "\n";
print "Total: ", $obj->getTotal(), "\n";
print "Mean: ", $obj->getMean(), "\n";
}
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Did you `use strict` and `use warnings`? That will help you fix a few problems…

Comment: If this is a homework problem, it should be tagged as such

Comment: @gcbenison Wrong, the homework tag is [*deprecated*](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated?cb=1)

Comment: You pass some arguments to the class constructor but never use them inside of the constructor?

Comment: Interesting fact No. 2019: The `’` character (*typographic apostrophe* or *right single quotation mark*) is not `'`. It is an unicode character and not ASCII. To use unicode characters in your source, `use utf8`. Outside of the Perl code, `use SensibleEditor qw(sane settings)` might also help. In this case, the "quotation" could also be ommited.

Comment: Your code has a lot of basic errors completely unrelated to any object oriented Perl. You may have to learn the language a bit more before thinking about inheritance and polymorphism..

Comment: Just noticed that you are also returning $this instead of $self from the constructor.

Comment: Can anyone please tell me what are the changes in the script I need to make to get the proper output? Please. Thanks in advance

Comment: Again, you should `use strict` and `use warnings`. This will point out  most problems with your code. I am sure you can then fix these problems, because the error messages will point out the problems quite clearly. At that point, the code will compile and run without complaining, but still won't work. At this point (but not earlier), you can update your question with the fixed code, and ask for further help that I will gladly provide if neccessary.

Comment: Still not getting the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. The object constructor syntax you are using is a bit akward, I'd prefer

```
my $obj = Stats->new(13,4,56,43,33);
```

In Perl, `new` is not an ordinary keyword, but a simple sub, and should be used as such. The `Foo->sub(@args)` syntax is exactly equivalent to `Foo::sub('Foo', @args)`, and thus takes care of passing the correct class name and calling the correct `new` sub.

Then, you should use the numbers you are passing to your `Stats` constructor. This constructor should do the trick:

```
sub new {
  my ($class, @args) = @_;
  my $self = {};
  bless $self, $class;
  $self->clear();
  $self->addValue($_) foreach @args;
  return $self;
}
```

I stuff all arguments of the constructor into the `@args` array and then loop over them and add these values to our stats object.

Also, do not forget to actually call `results()` to execute your test. It will print:

```
Number of values: 5
Total: 149
Mean: 29.8
```